# Tinymce editor Error

Tags: javascript, tinymce, rte

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD
 XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head> <title>Full featured
 example</title> <script
 type="text/javascript"
 src="../tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 tinyMCE.init({
     mode : "textareas",
     theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,undo,redo,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,cut,copy,paste,separator,link,unlink,separator,code,separator,image,formatselect",
     theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
     theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
     plugins : "imagemanager", 
     document_base_url : "http://localhost/htmllatest/admin",
     relative_urls : false, 
     content_css : "css/content.css",  relative_urls : false, 
         remove_script_host : false, }); </script> </head> <body> <form
 method="post" action="somepage">
  <textarea name="content"
 style="width:100%">  </textarea>
 </form> </body> </html>
```

Ths is my code for tinyeditor .But it is not working.Firefox ErrorConsole is showing the error Tinymce is not defined.anybody please tell me why this is not working

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure whether `tiny_mce.js` is present and gets loaded at all.

You could use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) and look into its "Net" tab (Screenshot [here](http://getfirebug.com/network))

Comment: Fire is not installed in my pc..let me do this

Comment: But an error like this is showing in error console invalid quantifier +;q=p}}return o},split:function(u,s,y){var z=this,o=z.createRng(),v,q,x;function p(A){var t,r=A.childNodes;if(A.nodeType==1&&A.getAttribute("_mce_type")=="bookmark"){return}for(t=r.length-1;t>=0;t--){p(r[t])}if(A.nodeType!=9){if(A.nodeType==3&&A.nodeValue.length>0){return}if(A.nodeType==1){r=A.childNodes;if(r.length==1&&r[0]&&r[0].nodeType==1&&r[0].getAttribute("_mce_type")=="bookmark"){A.parentNode.insertBefore(r[0],A)}if(r.length||
Source File: http://localhost/htmllatest/admin/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js
Line: 1

Comment: @user download a new, uncompressed version of TinyMCE and try using that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the tinyMCE library hasn't been included in your page. Check your  src's are correct and that the files are loaded using something like Firebug in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the minified version of TinyMCE is screwed up, try to load only tiny_mce_src.js to make sure everything is alright...

Answer (score 0):

The plugin imagemanager in not there in the plugin folder. Remove plugin line and problem fixed.